# How does subscribe works for http request?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

How does subscribe method work when http client requests data from endpoint?

Does it work as single request http? What if source in endpoint has new data, subscribe shows it after first call?

Comment: You could check out [Exploring the HttpClientModule in Angular](https://indepth.dev/exploring-the-httpclientmodule-in-angular/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every HTTP Observable in Angular completes after the first response ([docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#httpclient-methods-return-one-value)). You can test this with the following code:

```js
http.get('/some/url').subscribe(
  (data) => console.log('Data received:', data),
  (err) => console.log('Error received:', err),
  () => console.log('Observable completed and will not emit any data ever again.')
);
```

Comment: So, client dows not know about new changes of source after complete?

Comment: No, because HTTP is a unidirectional protocol, only the client can initiate communication by sending a request message and the server can only reply with 1 response (some exceptions like chunked responses maybe). For the server to be able to notify the client of new data another protocol like WebSocket is needed.

Comment: Another way around this without moving to WebSockets are polling and long-polling techniques. With polling you periodically ask the server again if something changed, with long-polling you ask and wait for a response, and the server only responds when something changed, then you ask again, waiting for the next change.

Comment: How then systems work, where need to send million messages to millions online users, as it works in taxi applications? When order sends to all millions drivers

Comment: They have very big servers :) And they engineer *scalable* solutions: They won't send every order to ALL of their drivers, just to the 100 closest who are available. But all large realtime apps probably use WebSocket but I am no authority on those things. I just use HTTP & WS to mess around :)

Comment: Sending millions of messages to millions of users probably puts you in range of being a tech giant like Facebook or WhatsApp

Comment: Do you know any tutorials about it?

Comment: Polling: https://nehalist.io/polling-in-angular/#component
WebSocket (low level): https://blog.angulartraining.com/how-to-use-websockets-with-rxjs-and-angular-b98e7fd8be82
WebSocket (higher level socket.io API): https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io

*Disclaimer*: I am a maintainer with 0 commits on the last linked package

Comment: For long polling you just poll client-side and every time you time out or receive a response you poll again. Server side you have to block the responding thread until a change or timeout occurs. But I'd say this is the most complicated route with no real advantages to you

Comment: In HTTP2, the server can send data to the client without the client requesting that data (i.e. [server push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2_Server_Push))